# Possible to update a UIViewController that is not on screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a side menu controller that is part of the `rootViewController`I never remove it from there and when it slides off screen - its just an animation that updates its `frame` details.

Is it possible to update this view, while it is not displayed on scene? I have a UiTableView in there and I would like to reload it while it is off screen - so when the user slides out the screen, its already populated with new content.

My first approach was a delegate - however, the delegate method doesn't get fired and I believe this is due to it being off screen. But, I somehow think side its in UIWindow it is never really deallocated like a normal view when it leaves the screen?

**Edit**

I am using [this Github project](https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu) for the menu.

The view I want to update is in a UINavigation controller, one level deep. I can get the current instance of it - however, the delegate method doesn't trigger.

Comment: You can do it by either accessing array of side view controller with its object or make array globally accessible by defining it in appdelegate and then reload tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are going with [something like this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/implementing-container-containment-sliding-menu-controller--mobile-14562). Even if not, look at the example. Here RootViewController is always alive and you move one viewcontroller to parent view controller and remove other one.

I have two ways to fix it:

1. If you are removing first view from parent view controller. Don't remove it. So the controller is still live and use delegates to trigger the event.
2. Remove first view controller then use Root view controller to get the updates and once the previous view controller loads back take updates from root view controller and update this one.

Hope it can atleast give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I should have mentioned in my question; I am using this project for the slide menu from github - https://github.com/mobivery/MVYSideMenu it is always part of UIWindow / rootviewController. I never remove it from there. The menu has a navigation controller and the view I need to update is one level deep. I can get the instance of the view controller - but the delegate doesn't fire. Not sure if you're suggestions would help with this?

Comment: A quick explore of this library depicts that the idea is same and the preivous controller gets removed and the new one moves to the root view controller. My thoughts appears to be valid for this library too.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have much experience with managing view controllers from root view and removing / adding. I'll do some experimenting now and come back to this question afterwards.

Comment: Use my link for experiment and understanding.